# Consume legacy rest api dependent upon WP API plugin

Tags: plugins, rest-api, wp-api

Is there any way to consume rest-api of WordPress plugins which were originally dependent upon the WP-API plugin in recent versions (v4.7 or later) of WordPress?

In my case, I want to use the rest-api of WP Project Mangaer plugin. The documentation seems quite old and have not been updated to use with latest versions of WordPress.

The [documentation](https://wedevs.com/docs/wp-project-manager/developer-docs/rest-api/) for WP Project Manager states that:

> WP Project Manager API is made following the REST method and is
>   dependent on WP-API plugin available on github. So you need to have
>   this plugin installed on your system and wp pro

I've tried the routes mentioned in documentation but any endpoint for `cpm-json` is not available. Guide me so I am able to use the rest-api provided by the [WP Project Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wedevs-project-manager/) plugin.

Plugin code implementing rest api:
https://github.com/weDevsOfficial/wp-project-manager/tree/develop/includes/cpm-api

Comment: It will depend on the plugin. You should ask the author.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I've opened support ticket, no reply. Its a free plugin, maybe someone able to help by taking a look at code.